# Need help connect relay to surveillance camera

Tags: relay, camera

I am seeking help.  I am NOT an electrical engineer!

I have a D-Link DCS-5222 camera that I am using for security.  I have made an IR LED array to provide illumination when the camera is in IR mode.  I am trying to connect a relay between the camera DO and the light source so that the light will turn on when triggered by motion.

The LED array uses a 12VDC power supply and draws approximately 960mA.

The only documentation I have for the camera's DI/DO is below.

[image: Camera DI/DO schematic]

I have a 5VDC,1 CHANNEL HIGH/LOW LEVEL INPUT, photo and specs below.  I do not have any datasheet for the relay.

[image: Relay]

--Relay specs--

Module description:
1. MAXIMUM LOAD RATINGS : AC 250V/10A, DC 30V/10A;
2. using SMD optocoupler isolation, driving ability, stable performance; trigger current 5mA;
3. 12VDC Operating voltage
4. the module can be set for a high or a low level input by a jumper setting for each channel 
5. Relay is rated at 12VDC Coil , OUTPUT CLOSURE CONTACTS @ 10 AMPS 250VAC/30VDC
6. BOARD POWER INDICATOR IS GREEN LED AND THE RELAY STATUS INDICATORS ARE RED
7. ALL TERMINAL CONNECTIONS FOR THE I/O CONNECTIONS 
8. MODULE DIMENSIONS EACH BOARD; 1 15/16"D X 1"W X 3/4"T

Module interface:
1. DC+: positive power supply (VCC)
2. DC-: negative power supply (GND)
3. IN: can be high or low level control relay

Relay outputs:
1. NO: normally open relay interface
2. COM: Common Interface Relays
3. NC: normally closed relay interface

High and low level trigger options:
It is low level trigger when jumper connect to LOW pin
It is high level trigger when jumper connect to HIGH pin

--END OF SPECS--

Can anyone help me figure out how to connect between the camera and the relay? I am trying to power the low side of the relay from the camera.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How will the camera detect motion if the light isn't already on? In any case, this is a question about the use of equipment, not its design, which is off-topic here.

Comment: The camera has it's own IR light source (four IR LEDs which surround the lens).  It also has passive IR motion detection.    I think I am trying to design the interface between the light source and the camera.  I did design the light source (with assistance from the "helpful" friends at this site), but, thanks for your response!

Comment: Although it mentions the wrong coil voltage, your relay spec implies an optoisolated control circuit which is visible on the board.  Based on that you should be able to connect the 5V and ground to the DC input pins, connect DO to IN and experiment with the position of the jumper to get the desired sense of on vs off.

Comment: The more troublesome issue is where the relay coil power is going to come from.  The camera may not be up to it, and the LED supply is the wrong voltage for the 5v coil relays (mismatching your spec) shown.  It's not clear which way the board is designed - opto isolation of the input implies the coil power comes from somewhere else, but the output has only 3 terminals, so apparently not from there.  Examination of the board should sort it out.

Comment: There is no data about input signal level, further it has an opto coupler, but the negative pin is shared between two voltage potentials, not clear. It would be easier to connect the relay directly as shown in the manual with flywheeling diode.

Comment: Chris.  Thanks for your help.  I did try to connect the 5 VDC output from the camera to relay DC+, camera GND to DC- and camera DO to relay IN.  I then tried switching the relay jumper fro the high to low position.  I then tried to trigger the event.  The relay board has a green LED for power on and red LED for relay status.  neither LED illuminated.

Comment: Forget about the camera for the moment. Can you get the relay to work/trigger just by connecting its coil/opto-input to a DC source?

Comment: Fluff.  Good idea.  I connected the relay to a separate 5 VDC power supply and the green (power on) LED illuminated.  I guess I need to either use a 5 VDC power supply or get a 12 volt relay and power it from the LED array power supply.  I am still confused by the schematic for the "Internal 5V Power," which is the one I was planning to use.

Comment: From the schematic for the internal 5V power, id there a way to power the relay from the camera?

Answer (score 1):

Just want to post the resolution in case anyone else ends up here with the same issue.

First, I have to admit I was being lazy because I didn't want to remove the camera from its mount to bring it to a place where I could do tests.

I checked the voltage across camera pins 2 and 4.  I found 5VDC.  I connected camera pins 2 and 4 to the relay pins DC+ and DC-.  Resulted in green "power" LED illuminated.

Next, I connected camera pin 1 to relay pin "IN." To test, I went to the camera setup page and changed the digital output state from NO to NC.  No effect.  I then moved the relay jumper from low to high.  At that point, I was able to change relay by changing the digital output state on the camera.

Calling it solved.  Now I just need to decide where to mount the relay and how to make the connections.

Thanks for all the assistance.  I love this site!